# Example of a finite commutative ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ where $I$ is maximal but not prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Example of a finite commutative ring $R$ whose maximal ideal $I$ is not prime?

Is it possible? I am not able to find such example.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Right after I answered I noticed a very good duplicate in the items to the right. Among the solutions is the one I offered ($2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$), plus more.

Comment: @hardmath I came up with a compromise, considering the asker's difficulty seeing the connection.

Comment: @Kangmin If you had read the solutions at the duplicates, you would have noticed that [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/452698/29335) already does what you want. So indeed, your question is already answered elsewhere.  Therefore a duplicate link is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. For any commutative ring with $1$, any maximal ideal is prime.

**Hint.** use characterization of prime/maximal ideals in terms of quotient rings

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible if you ring lacks an identity.

Perhaps you didn't notice, but this is trivially derived from [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/452338/29335), where
$R=2\mathbb Z$ and $M=4\mathbb Z$ is given as an example, but obviously in the quotient $R/M$ has order $2$ and its zero ideal is maximal and nonprime.

Similarly [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2031282/29335) can be adapted by saying $R=6\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ has a maximal nonprime zero ideal (it is isomorphic to the ring above, as a matter of fact.)

And in fact [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/452698/29335) is exactly what you're asking for.  So remember when you are reading duplicates, check their solutions too, because sometimes they do *more* than what the question asks of them.